# What would be a good auto-scaling and ELB configuration for a heavy-traffic Wordpress site on Amaon EC2?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2, varnish, php

We've recently launched a news site that runs on Wordpress.(WP) The WP installation is on Amazon EC2 single micro instance with Nginx, PHP-fpm and Varnish. ([As described in this tutorial](http://theartofcode.tv/installing-wordpress-on-ec2/)) We don't have any cache plugins activated yet.

We are getting around 30k to 60k unique visitors daily. The site is putting up pretty well. At a particular moment, we have around 400-500 active visitors.

Now the site went down once. we rebooted the EC2 instance & it went up again. So we're guessing the instance isn't able to take the load. Is it correct? How can I check the exact cause?

**1. Shall we move to a small instance and make it auto-scalable + ELB?** or

**2. Shall we make the micro instance auto-scalable + ELB?**

**3. What would be a good configuration for our use case?**

Please guide as we're relatively new to Amazon EC2, auto-scaling and ELB. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, problems like this take hands on access to track down, the kind of work my company usually handles :) . With that in mind, you have some good software at work here. Nginx and Varnish work very well together, and should withstand a heavy punch. We have a few clients who have very high traffic sites running Apache (slower than Nginx) with Varnish in front of it, and they get way more traffic than you are saying, with little to no performance problems. Certainly not a server crash.

With these facts, immediately my attention is drawn to your software configurations and your hardware. It seems to me that you need to use some of the tools that come with varnish and see if it is working to it's full potential. Chances are it needs tuning. It is very powerful if configured properly. Try changing the storage type to malloc. Try giving it a gig or two of ram to play with. That should handle moderate traffic like a champ, with absolutely no problems.

Next look at your hardware. How many cores do you have available to you? What is your memory capacity? What are the restraints on your connection speed? Not enough cores can absolutely slow you down. If you have a dual core instance, your are gunna get out performed by a quad-core, or an eight-core. How about memory? 1GB of memory simply wont cut it for your traffic. Id say minimum you need 4GB, 2 of that for varnish alone. If your connection is super slow, then you have to spend more time waiting for a request to send out, which makes your whole system lag out. Eventually you could have more requests coming in than you can send out.

Lastly, you had a question about caching plugins for WordPress. Yes caching plugins can be a server saver. That being said, they are usually a precursor to finding that you need an actual cache solution, like Nginx with Varnish. WP caching plugins are great, for sites that have less traffic than your say you have. They are a stepping stone between no caching and server software caching, like you have. After you setup Nginx and Varnish, you get absolutely zero added value out of having a WP caching plugin. I do not recommend investing any appreciable amount of time into researching them, because you are well past the point of their usefulness.

In conclusion, this is a big picture type problem, almost 100% of the time. My company has solved the caching problem for sites with 10,000 page views a month all the way to half a billion page views a month. The idea behind your setup sounds good, but it sounds like you need some hardware consideration and some tuning by a person who knows how what to tune and how to tune it. A consulting company, like mine, would be able to give you some exact reasons, and paths to resolution, with some hands on investigation.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth analysis. I just switched to m1.small instance on Amazon which has the following config: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#on-demand. I know it's below what you suggested for, but I think we'll stick to it to observe how it works and then upgrade accordingly. Btw, you're correct, we need some expert, but being a small startup, we don't have the money to afford one. Hence the great folks at Stackoverflow helps anyday!

Comment: Well the price is right :) startups can be tough. Best I can really say is sit down and do some research specifically on Varnish. If it is tuned right it can work wonders. There is a lot of good information available on their website, but I'm sure if you crafted some specific questions, the stackoverflow hive-mind can muster an answer :)